# Where can I get a list of Unicode chars by class?

Tags: c#, unicode, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm new to learning Unicode, and not sure how much I have to learn based on my ASCII background, but I'm reading [the C# spec on rules for identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx) to determine what chars are permitted within [Azure Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338.aspx) (which is directly based on the C# spec).

Where can I find a list of Unicode characters that fall into these categories:

- `letter-character`: A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl
- `combining-character`: A Unicode character of classes Mn or Mc
- `decimal-digit-character`: A Unicode character of the class Nd
- `connecting-character`: A Unicode character of the class Pc
- `formatting-character`: A Unicode character of the class Cf

Comment: @Hans Passant, that regex is just for a table name, not for an identifier that is used in property names such as PartitionKey and RowKey

Comment: @Hans: Very wrong comment. A-Za-Z covers 52 Unicode characters out of thousands that are permissible letters.

Comment: @Timwi - oh, I did not know that.  I quoted from the docs of course.

Comment: @Hans: What docs? Link? The C# language specification clearly states “A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl; or A *unicode-escape-sequence* representing a character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl” (§2.4.2 Identifiers). MakerOfThings7 even linked to this in the question.

Comment: @Timwi - the OP knew what I meant.  Good enough for me.

Comment: Timwi: Looks like @HansPassant was misreading the docs linked by the OP, and misunderstood the "table names" section in the [Azure Table docs linked by the OP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (which indeed is restricted to those few characters) as being relevant. Of course, the question is not about table names.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can retrieve this information in an automated fashion from the official Unicode data file, `UnicodeData.txt`, which is published here:

- [UnicodeData.txt (at unicode.org)](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)

This is a file with semicolon-separated values in each line. The third column tells you the character class of each character.

The benefit of this is that you can get the character name for each character, so you have a better idea of what it is than by just looking at the character itself (e.g. would you know what ბ is? That’s right, it’s Ban. In Georgian. `:-)`)

Comment: Nice! I can even search for chars within each category like this ";Cf;"

Comment: ...I never in my life thought Unicode was this complex.  Seems like I have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: this is wierd. It says in the text file the "#" sign is a "Sc" category, MSDN says [the same](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.110).aspx) but it is in fact a "OtherPunctuation" i.e. "Ps". Bug in .net 4.5.1?

Comment: @Marcus: I think you were looking at the wrong line. It says Po for the # character, and Sc for the next one, the dollar sign.

Comment: @Timwi ok I might have but my debugger still says # is Ps, not Po or any other category. Having # in such a large group as "OtherPunctuation" seems like a bug in .net to me.

Comment: @Timwi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:General_Category_(Unicode) this link says in "LO" category there are 121,212 characters, but in the link you posted there are only 16053 char under "LO", is there any reason?

Comment: @oliversmith The file I linked to does not list all of the Han (Chinese) characters separately, but as a range: `4E00;<CJK Ideograph, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;` / `9FEF;<CJK Ideograph, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;`

Comment: The description of the file format is here (including the list of character ranges represented by only the start and end characters): http://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/UnicodeData.html

Answer (score 38):

FileFormat.info has a list of Unicode characters by category:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

Comment: That site doesn't parse UnicodeData.txt right. It doesn't recognize ranges and doesn't understand Cn. So the categories Co, Cs, Lo, and Cn have the wrong counts. Other than that it's a cool site.

Answer (score 16):

You can, of course, use LINQ:

```
var charInfo = Enumerable.Range(0, 0x110000)
                         .Where(x => x < 0x00d800 || x > 0x00dfff)
                         .Select(char.ConvertFromUtf32)
                         .GroupBy(s => char.GetUnicodeCategory(s, 0))
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

foreach (var ch in charInfo[UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter])
{
    Console.Write(ch);
}
```

You can find a list of Unicode categories and their short names on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx), e.g., "Ll" is short for [UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx).

Comment: How did you know to hard code those constants in?  Where do they come from?

Comment: @MakerOfThings7: From the documentation of [Char.ConvertFromUtf32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32.aspx). It throws an exception if its argument "is not a valid 21-bit Unicode code point ranging from U+0 through U+10FFFF, excluding the surrogate pair range from U+D800 through U+DFFF."

Comment: Linq is fun.  +1 since I'm going to learn something from this.  Also I think not all chars will render within "Console.write".  Perhaps it's better for me to output these codes in a HTML page for IE to render?

Comment: @MakerOfThings7: Yes, the set of characters the Console can display is quite limited. Writing the characters to a HTML page is a good idea.

Comment: I'm convinced that  char.GetUnicodeCategory gives incorrect results. U+0E33 should (imo) give me the result SpacingCombiningMark, but it returns 'OtherLetter'. This does not seem right to me.

Comment: @Gusdor The Unicode Standard says it is of type `OtherLetter` for sentence. You are perhaps looking for Grapheme Cluster Break, which I am not sure is available in C#.

Answer (score 2):

In the [ANTLR lexer](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/b97ad8c2147fe78677b4dac6a1da6877edf27ec5/antlr4/LexUnicode.g4) you can find Unicode character sets (LU, LL, LT, LM, and LO) in convenient range format.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category is a pretty useful and easy-to-navigate site for browsing the categories. 
It is searchable and lists quite a lot of info on individual unicode characters.