# how to find position of last alphabet from string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, special-characters

Hi I have  a mix type  of  string.  i  want  to  remove  special  symbol  from  word   which  are  using  end  of  the  words  only.
for ex.

```
 "Kapil-Kumar?hasija--
```

i  need  to  remove special  symbols  which  are  coming  after  my   sentence.  So  for  this  i  need  to  find  position  of  my   last  alphabet.

Comment: i  am  using  Asp.net  with c#

Comment: always special characters will be at the end of string?

Comment: You're not looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742495/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-unicode-chars-by-class ?

Comment: no  they  can  be  anywhere   but  i  need  to remove only from  end  of  the  my word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
string s = "Kapil-Kumar?hasija--";

while (s.Length > 0 && !Char.IsLetter(s[s.Length-1]))
  s = s.Substring(0, s.Length-1);

Console.WriteLine(s); // prints "Kapil-Kumar?hasija"
```

If digits are also permitted at the end, use `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` instead of `Char.IsLetter`.