# unicode general category z* in whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet

Tags: ios, nsscanner, nscharacterset

in nscharacterset class there is whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet method which returns few unicodes,
 i was wondering what  is z*,i searched online but couldn't find any explanations.

can anyone tell what does unicode category z* mean exactly???  [do seee image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNINO.png)

Answer (score 3):

Category Z* are separators

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zl/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zp/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/index.htm

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742569/78496