# In the C# Language Specification what is meant by "Any character with Unicode class Zs"?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, syntax

Just reading a web page here on the C# language specificaion
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664665(v=vs.71).aspx
there is some text that says "Any character with Unicode class Zs", in the context of defining white space.

Please,  what is meant by "Any character with Unicode class Zs"?

It might be linked to regular expressions, adding regex tag.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742495/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-unicode-chars-by-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode codepoints have a classification assigned to each of them.  Codepoints in the `Zs` class belong to the ["Separator, Space"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm) category.

Comment: That's really good, I am looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java.   Do all these characters match together with regular expression [\s\u0085\p{Z}] as per an answer in that post?

Comment: Ok, will accept this now, will go on to test some regular expressions in Java to see if [\s\u0085\p{Z}] works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means whitespace characters (separators). Check out this link http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm