# PHP - how to count the number of leading spaces in a multi-byte / UTF-8 string correctly

Tags: php

I have UTF-8 strings such as those below:

21st century

Other languages

General collections

Ancient languages

Medieval languages

Several authors (Two or more languages)

As you can see, the strings contain alphanumeric characters as well leading and trailing spaces.

I'd like to use PHP to retrieve the number of leading spaces (not trailing spaces) in each string. Note that the spaces might be non-standard ASCII spaces. I tried using:

```
var_dump(mb_ord($space_char, "UTF-8"));
```

where the `$space_char` contains a sample space character I copied from one of the above strings, and I got 160 rather than 32.

I have tried:

```
strspn($string,$cmask); // $cmask contains a string with two space characters with 160 and 32 as their Unicode code points.
```

but I get a very unpredictable value.

The values should be:

```
(1) 12
(2) 6
(3) 9
(4) 9
(5) 9
(6) 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the regular expression route:

```
<?php
function count_leading_spaces($str) {
    // \p{Zs} will match a whitespace character that is invisible,
    // but does take up space
    if (mb_ereg('^\p{Zs}+', $str, $regs) === false)
        return 0;
    return mb_strlen($regs[0]);
}

$samples = [
'            21st century ',
'      Other languages ',
'         General collections ',
'         Ancient languages ',
'         Medieval languages ',
'            Several authors (Two or more languages) ',
];

foreach ($samples as $i => $sample) {
    printf("(%d) %d\n", $i + 1, count_leading_spaces($sample));
}
```

Output:

```
(1) 12
(2) 6
(3) 9
(4) 9
(5) 9
(6) 12
```

Comment: What are some examples of whitespace characters that are invisible? [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128) (U+200B)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534155/in-the-c-sharp-language-specification-what-is-meant-by-any-character-with-unico

Answer (score 1):

## Code

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$s = "            21st century 
      Other languages 
         General collections 
         Ancient languages 
         Medieval languages 
            Several authors (Two or more languages) ";

preg_match_all('/^([\s]*)[\S]/msu', $s, $leading);
# print_r($leading);
# echo mb_strlen($leading[1][0])."\n";
# echo mb_strlen($leading[1][1])."\n";
# echo mb_strlen($leading[1][2])."\n";
# echo mb_strlen($leading[1][3])."\n";
# echo mb_strlen($leading[1][4])."\n";
# echo mb_strlen($leading[1][5])."\n";
function print_leading_len($v, $k)
{
    echo mb_strlen($v)."\n";
}
array_walk($leading[1], 'print_leading_len');
```

## Output

```
12
6
9
9
9
12
```

- *[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)*
- *[mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-strlen.php)*

Comment: An explanation (in the answer, not here in comments) would be in order. E.g., what is the regular expression supposed to do? Why is the "\S" part necessary? Can't it just match white space from the beginning of the line? What is array_walk() for?